# NodeJS: server responds extremely slowly while uploading 5+ photos

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, multipartform-data, multer

When I'm uploading more than 5 photos at same time (5 multipart/form-data request), during its process, any GET request has **~500ms delay**, any Socket.io event has **~1500ms delay**.

Is this normal? I tried with [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) and [Multiparty](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty) as upload middleware, both give the same lag.

The photos are each about 5MB large. The CPU usage for of node process during the upload raises about 5% than average, and memory usage stays normal.

**Server**: Hosted on DigitalOcean. Ubuntu with 1G RAM, 1 Core Processor, 30G SSD

Does anyone experience the same thing? Here's a snippet for [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer). I would really appreciate for any help, I've been trying to solve this for 5 days now without any success :(

```
function photoUpload(req, res, next){
    dest: 'public/photos',
    limits: { fileSize: 10*1000000 }, // 10MB file limit
    onFileSizeLimit: function (file) { fs.unlink(file.path) },
    onParseEnd: function (req, next) { 
        var file = req.files.photo;
        file.url = '/photos/' + file.name; // save photo url
        next(); 
    }
}

app.post('/api/upload', photoUpload, function(req, res){
    Database.createPhoto(req.file.url); // save photo url in database
});
```

Comment: How fast is the upload from where you are uploading the photos? It sounds like you may be saturating your entire upload bandwidth.